# What does @(Page.NavId ..) Do?

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I have inherited code for a website I am developing in C#/Razor, and don't exactly understand what the  following code @(Page.NavID...) does in the following line  in the _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li @(Page.NavId == "Page1" ? @Html.Raw("class='active'") : @Html.Raw(""))>
    <a href="~/Page1.cshtml">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"</span> &nbsp;&nbsp; Page 1 content
    </a>
  </li>
```

I understand the Lambda expression, but where do I find the definition for NavId? Is this a method off of the Page object???  Any help appreciated.

Comment: "I understand the Lambda expression," Except there is no lambda expression here present. That's just an expression with a ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a [Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/) app, not a Razor Pages app. `NavId` was not part of the API for that framework, so it is possibly a property of a base class implemented by the original developers that itself derives from [`WebPage`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/main/src/System.Web.WebPages/WebPage.cs).

If F12 doesn't help you locate the definition, you could try searching the contents of the application files.

From the code you posted, I suggest that `NavId` represents the name of the current page (possibly obtained from a database). The ternary expression (it's not a lambda) switches the CSS class of the list item to "active" if the current page is "Page1".

There is no need for the `Html.Raw` methods calls in that code. It would have been better (more concise) as follows:

```
<li class="@(Page.NavId == "Page1" ? "active" : null)">
```